# Get all HTML elements scrolled into view

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I've got a scrollable table in HTML that updates frequently (about once per second) and can contain upwards of 1000 rows. Obviously, it's not reasonable to replace the entire table every time it updates, so I'd like to just replace the table rows that are currently visible.

My first attempt was to just check iterate over all the rows and check their offsets; this works, but it's far too slow to be effective.

What I'm trying to do now is use `document.elementFromPoint()` to find the topmost element overtop the `<tbody>`, which is usually a `<td>` element from where I can get its containing `<tr>`. This almost works, except in the case where the table itself is obscured by another element (a floating lightbox, for example).

I'm currently looking for either a third solution, or a way to get all elements under a specific point, not just the topmost one. If anyone has any idea how to accomplish either of those, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: why wouldn't you paginate the rows?

Comment: That occurred to me, but it's not as nice for the user to have to swap pages as opposed to just scrolling - same reason why the infinite scroll technique is popular.

Comment: I don't know if you're using/willing to use jQuery, but [this plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport) seems to fit your needs if I'm not misunderstanding.

Comment: Using MooTools so jQuery is out, but I might try implementing something like that and see. Probably still going to be too slow, since it needs to check all the elements.

Comment: Not right now, but I could probably modify the design so they will be. I can't count on pixel consistency though, since I don't have control over font size etc.

Answer (score 0):

So I was thinking about this one and came up with this.

http://jsfiddle.net/RKzRE/7/

Instead of monitoring all 1000 rows just monitor a subset of them. Cache their scrolltops on page load for efficiency. So what if you update a few rows above or below the display area? You can find a happy medium between granularity and speed of updates.

I only implemented scrolling down and hardcoded the number of rows to update. But I think the details will be easy to figure out.

```
//create an object to hold a list of row top locations
var rowmarkers = new Object;

//gather all rows and store their top location
$('tr').each(function(index) {
    //create markers for every ten rows
    if (index % 10 == 0) {
        $(this).addClass('marker');
        rowmarkers[$(this).prop('id')] = $(this).offset().top;
    }
});

//track whether user scrolls up or down 
var prevScrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();

//monitor scroll event
$(document).scroll(function() {
    var currentScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (currentScrollTop > prevScrollTop) {
        downScroll(currentScrollTop);
    } else {
        //up
    }
    prevScrollTop = currentScrollTop;
});

function downScroll(scrollTop) {
    //find the first row that is visible on screen
    for (var row in rowmarkers) {
        if (rowmarkers[row] > scrollTop) {
            //all rows after this can be updated
            var updaterow = $('#' + row).prevAll('.marker:first');
            if (!updaterow.length) { updaterow = $('.marker:first'); }
            //hardcoded # of rows to update
            for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                console.log($(updaterow).prop('id'));
                updaterow = updaterow.next('tr');
                updaterow.not('.marker').addClass('updaterow');
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```